# only one element at time can be "toggleClass"-ed in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, time, element

How I am able to toggleClass on elements, but only one can be "toggled" at time.
There is solution (by adding another for loop to disable effect), but in pureJS and I need help to get this work in jQuery.

```js
var elements = document.querySelectorAll("#box");

for ( var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++ ) (function(i){ 
  elements[i].onclick = function() {
    for (var j = 0; j < elements.length; j++) {
      elements[j].style.border = '';
      elements[j].innerHTML = '';
    }
    elements[i].style.border = "10px solid red";
    elements[i].innerHTML = "selected";
  };
})(i);
```

```css
body {background-color: black;}
#box {
  background: white;
  color: red;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 1%;
}
#box.red{
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="box"></div>
  <div id="box"></div>
  <div id="box"></div>
  <div id="box"></div> 
</body>
```

And here is jQuery function. In-short, I need that **only one box can be red** at time and when another is clicked it disable selected one. Exactly like one above in javascript.

```js
$("div#box").click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass("red");  
});
```

```css
body {background-color: black;}
#box {
  background: white;
  color: red;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 1%;
}
#box.red{
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div id="box"></div>
  <div id="box"></div>
  <div id="box"></div>
  <div id="box"></div>
  
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual way to do this is to remove the class on all of the other possible 'toggles' before applying the class to the newly selected one, like this:

```
var boxes = $('div.box');

boxes.click(function(){
  boxes.removeClass('red');
  $(this).addClass('red');  
});
```

(You should use a class, not an ID any time you have more than one element to apply it to (so I've used `.box`, not `#box`).

Another important point is to select the boxes only once, and store them in a variable outside of the click handler. That way, you're not always re-selecting them on every click.

Comment: Thank you very much, exactly the solution I was looking for.

Comment: No problem. For extra points (and forgive me if this is just from your demo code), you should use a class like `'selected'` instead of `red` to apply the selected state. That way, when someone decides that selected items should be blue, you only have to change your CSS!

Comment: Yes I know, it was just an example. :)

Answer (score 2):

the this, refers to the current clicked element.
you will need to apply it to all the nav items such as below.

```js
var 
$boxes = $("div#box").click(function(){
  $boxes.removeClass("red"); 
  $(this).addClass("red");  
});
```

```css
body {background-color: black;}
#box {
  background: white;
  color: red;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 1%;
}
#box.red{
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div id="box"></div>
  <div id="box"></div>
  <div id="box"></div>
  <div id="box"></div>
  
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Like previously said use a class instead of an ID. You can use the .not() jQuery method to achieve this.

*Note:* The difference between Beejamin's answer and mine is that in this one you can toggle the red class clicking the same square again while also removing siblings selection.

```js
var box = $(".box");
box.click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("red");
  box.not(this).removeClass("red");
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

.box {
  background: white;
  color: red;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 1%;
}

.red {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```